# python use carriage return to re-write multiple lines

Tags: python-3.x, carriage-return

Let's say I had a list of multi-line strings:

```py
l = [
"""hello
world""",
"""this
is
a
multiline
string""",
"""foo
bar"""
]

for s in l:
    print(s)

hello
world
this
is
a
multiline
string
foo
bar
```

instead of printing a newline after each multiline string, I would like to print each element in the list where each iteration we will carriage return back to the begin such that the multiline string reprints over the last.

How can this be achieved in python3?

Comment: You can try printing a backspace character, or try printing a carriage return. Whether or not it will work though largely depends on the specific console. You can use a library like Curses too.

Answer (score 3):

You could use ANSI sequences and [colorama](https://github.com/tartley/colorama) module to make them working under Windows too.

This code is tested on Linux (bash) and Windows (CMD and PowerShell) consoles:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import colorama

colorama.init()

# ESC [ n A       # move cursor n lines up
# ESC [ n B       # move cursor n lines down
cursor_up = lambda lines: '\x1b[{0}A'.format(lines)
cursor_down = lambda lines: '\x1b[{0}B'.format(lines)

l = [
"""hello
world""",
"""this
is
a
multiline
string""",
"""foo
bar"""
]

max_lines = 0

for s in l:
    print(s)

    # count lines to reach the starting line
    lines_up = s.count('\n')+2

    # save maximum value
    if lines_up > max_lines:
        max_lines = lines_up

    # going up to the starting line
    print(cursor_up(lines_up))

# going down to ensure all output is preserved
print(cursor_down(max_lines))
```

Results:

```
>python test.py
fooso
barld
a
multiline
string
>
```